# What's equivalent to Django's auto_now, auto_now_add in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, django, date, sqlalchemy

In Django, we can use these 2 parameters when making a date column:

> DateField.auto_now Automatically set the field to now every time the
>   object is saved. Useful for “last-modified” timestamps. Note that the
>   current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that you
>   can override.
>
> DateField.auto_now_add Automatically set the field to now when the
>   object is first created. Useful for creation of timestamps. Note that
>   the current date is always used; it’s not just a default value that
>   you can override.

How to do this in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Finally, after checking the SQLAlchemy doc, this should be the way:

```
Column('created_on', DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.now)

Column('last_updated', DateTime, onupdate=datetime.datetime.now)
```

doc here:

[http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#python-executed-functions)

Comment: Good find. I'd recommend also creating a link to where in the docs that you found it.

Comment: Actually this isn't quite correct. To mimic Django, `last_updated` field should be `Column('last_updated', DateTime, default=datetime.now(), onupdate=datetime.now())` - as Django sets `auto_now` fields to `now` upon creation.

Comment: doc is returning 404.

Comment: Adding ```nullable=False``` would also be nice. In Alembic, if you check the revision file, by default it is set to ```nullable=True```

Comment: @samuraisam shouldn't it be `datetime.now` instead of `datetime.now()` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's still possible to use the following:

```py
enter_date = Column(DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, onupdate=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

On update also sqlalchemy set the current date at the time the data updates.